# Utilize established ssh tunnel from another shell?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, proxy, socks5-proxy

I have an established ssh tunnel (port 9876) that is running in the background and was established with this command:

```
/usr/bin/autossh -M 0 -o ServerAliveInterval 30 -o ServerAliveCountMax 3 -D 9876 user@example.com -i /path/to/keyfile -T -N -n
```

Let's say I cannot change anything about it. I can utilize the tunnel from applications like Firefox by specifying a socks5 proxy on `localhost` on port 9876.

My question is how can I utilize that existing tunnel from another bash shell?

I know of some specific tools allow using a local proxy in this way, such as curl:

```
curl -sS -x socks5://127.0.0.1:9876 icanhazip.com
```

However, I am interested in the general question of how to make any Internet connection from a bash shell utilize this existing ssh tunnel, without relying on a program to have that feature. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think the tsocks tool might be what you are looking for.

Comment: I believe you are talking about: http://tsocks.sourceforge.net/. It has not been updated in over 16 years. I'm not sure using it for a secure tunnel is a good idea...